# parameter count mismatch sqlite and qt error

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

i have error with sqlite query

i don't know where is the problem the problem exactly

i have make a default connexion in mainwindow.cpp

and i just get the default connexion and query the data base, but isn't works

her is my code so far

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::database() ;

QSqlQuery query ;

query.prepare("select seq from sqlite_sequence where name= ? ");

query.addBindValue("articles");

if(!query.exec())
{
    QMessageBox::critical(this,"Inventoria solti",query.lastError().text());
    return ;
}

while (query.next())
{
    ui->lineEdit->setText(query.value(0).toString());
}
```

her is the default connexion in mainwindow.cpp

```
m_db = new QSqlDatabase;
// Base de données traitement
*m_db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE") ;
m_db->setHostName("localhost");
m_db->setDatabaseName("E:/apprendreQt/gestionstock6/database/inventaire.db");
m_db->setPassword("");
m_db->setUserName("");
if(!m_db->open())
    QMessageBox::critical(this,"erreur connecting",m_db->lastError().text());
```

Comment: And what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: i get an error , "parameter count mismtach"

Comment: You have an empty database. Why do you expect it to contain tables?

Comment: i don't have an empty database , i was maked the default connexion to datbase in my mainwindow.cppp   like so     m_db = new QSqlDatabase;
    // Base de données traitement
    *m_db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE") ;
    m_db->setHostName("localhost");
    m_db->setDatabaseName("E:/apprendreQt/gestionstock6/database/inventaire.db");
    m_db->setPassword("");
    m_db->setUserName("");
    if(!m_db->open())
        QMessageBox::critical(this,"erreur connecting",m_db->lastError().text());

Comment: i just modified the post  in top

Comment: Try `"select seq from sqlite_sequence where name= 'articles' "`.

Comment: i get anothre error "No query try to fetch row"

Answer (score 0):

sorry, the problem was in the path of database witch is not correct

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::database() ;

QSqlQuery query ;

query.prepare("select seq from sqlite_sequence where name= ? ");

query.addBindValue("articles");

if(!query.exec())
{
    QMessageBox::critical(this,"Inventoria solti",query.lastError().text());
    return ;
}

while (query.next())
{
    ui->lineEdit->setText(query.value(0).toString());
}
```

her is the default connexion in mainwindow.cpp

```
m_db = new QSqlDatabase;
// Base de données traitement
*m_db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE") ;
m_db->setHostName("localhost");
m_db->setDatabaseName("E:/apprendreQt/gestionstock6/database/inventaire.db");
m_db->setPassword("");
m_db->setUserName("");
if(!m_db->open())
    QMessageBox::critical(this,"erreur connecting",m_db->lastError().text());
```